# "Invalid Fingerprint" Instance Group rolling out update fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Rolling update for an instance group fails with "Invalid Fingerprint" error message at console. Earlier rollouts had no issues but observing this error since today and updates are failing.

Any clues please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the command-line rolling update:

```
gcloud beta compute instance-groups managed rolling-action start-update <instancegroupname> --version template=<templatename> --zone asia-southeast1-b
```

Comment: command-line rollout worked! Console still shows the error but updates are in place through command-line. Thanks for helping out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, our Internal Compute Engine team working on the issue, The current workaround is to use the gcloud command which should also fix the issue on the Cloud Console afterwards. you can do a rolling replace using: gcloud beta compute instance-groups managed rolling-action replace [instance group]

You can find the details of the command [at this link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instance-groups/managed/rolling-action/). Also, you can keep an eye for complete resolution of the issue at this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123037732) link where other users field a defect report. I must also mention that Updating Managed Instance Group is a [beta feature](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups) as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here!
It's possibile only in the terminal way?

```
gcloud beta compute instance-groups managed rolling-action start-update <instancegroupname> --version template=<templatename> --zone asia-southeast1-b
```

This is the correct code?
It' can't work for me! (I have already a instance-group "example" and a template "example-template" created)